# CS50 PSET6 DNA no match using regex to count STR

Tags: python, cs50

I have been stuck at this point for quite a while, hope to get some tips.

The problem can be simplified as to find what is the largest consecutive occurrence of a pattern in a string. As a pattern `AATG`, for a string like `ATAATGAATGAATGGAATG` the right result should be 3. I tired to count the occurrences of the pattern by using `re.compile()`. I have found out from the doc that if i want to find consecutive occurrence of a pattern i possibly have to use special character `+`. For instance, a pattern like `AATG` i have to use `re.compile(r'(AATG)+')` instead of `re.compile(r'AATG')`. Otherwise, the occurrences will be overcounted. However, in this program the pattern is not a fixed string. I have treat it as a variable. I have tried many ways to put it into `re.compile()` without positive results. Could anyone enlighten me the correct way to format it (which is in the Function `def countSTR` below)?

After that, i think `finditer(the_string_to_be_analysis)` should return a iterator including all matches found. Then i used `match.end() - match.start()` to obtain the length of every match to compare with each other in order to get the longest consecutive occurrence of the pattern. maybe something goes wrong there?

code attached. Every input would be appreciated!

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv
import re

def main():
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
        exit(1)

    # read DNA sequence
    with open(argv[2], "r") as file:
        if file.mode != 'r':
            print(f"database {argv[2]} can not be read")
            exit(1)
        sequence = file.read()

    # read database.csv
    with open(argv[1], newline='') as file:
        if file.mode != 'r':
            print(f"database {argv[1]} can not be read")
            exit(1)
        # get the heading of the csv file in order to obtain STRs
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        headings = next(csv_reader)
        # dictionary to store STRs match result of DNA-sequence
        STR_counter = {}
        for STR in headings[1::]:
            # entry result accounting to the STR keys
            STR_counter[STR] = countSTR(STR, sequence)
    # read csv file as a dictionary
    with open(argv[1], newline='') as file:
        database = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in database:
            count = 0
            for STR in STR_counter:
                # print("row in database ", row[STR], "STR in STR_counter", STR_counter[STR])
                if int(row[STR]) == int(STR_counter[STR]):
                    count += 1
            if count == len(STR_counter):
                print(row['name'])
                exit(0)
        else:
            print("No match")

# find non-overlapping occurrences of STR in DNA-sequence
def countSTR(STR, sequence):
    count = 0
    maxcount = 0
    # in order to match repeat STR. for example: "('AATG')+" as pattern
    # into re.compile() to match repeat STR
    # rewrite STR to "(STR)+"
    STR = "(" + STR + ")+"
    pattern = re.compile(r'STR')
    # matches should be a iterator object
    matches = pattern.finditer(sequence)
    # go throgh every repeat and find the longest one
    # by match.end() - match.start()
    for match in matches:
        count = match.end() - match.start()
        if count > maxcount:
            maxcount = count
    # return repeat times of the longest repeat
    return maxcount/len(STR)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

just find out a correct way to get the desired result.
post it here in case any others are also confused.
From what I have understand, to match a variable named `var_pattern` could use `re.compile(rf'{var_pattern}')`. Then if consecutive occurrences of the var_pattern should be searched, could use `re.compile(rf'(var_pattern)+')`. There may be other smarter ways to implement that, however i managed to get it work as fine as previously .